# Approximation of $L^p$ functions by convolution of approximate identities

Tags: real-analysis, convolution, locally-compact-groups, haar-measure

We use the notation $\mathbb{K}$ to mean either the real number field $\mathbb{R}$ or the complex number field $\mathbb{C}$. Let $X$ be a locally compact group and let $\lambda$ denote the unique [Haar Measure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Haar_measure?wprov=sfla1) on the Borel sigma algebra of $X$. Recall that an approximate identity is a family $(u_\epsilon)_{\epsilon > 0} \subset L^1(X, \mathbb{K})$ satisfying

a) $\exists c>0$ such that $\|u_\epsilon\|_1 = \int_X |u_\epsilon| d\lambda < c$

b) $\forall \epsilon >0 \colon \int_X u_\epsilon = 1$

c) for any neighborhood $U$ of the neutral element $e \in X$ $$\int_{X\backslash U} |u_\epsilon| d\lambda \to 0$$ for $\epsilon \to 0$.

$\textbf{Lemma}$: Let $1 \leq p < \infty$ and suppose $f \in L^p(X, \mathbb{K})$, then for all $\delta>0$ there exists an open neighborhood $U$ of $e$ so that $$\int_X |f(x)-f(y^{-1}x)|^p d\lambda(x) \leq \delta$$ for all $y \in U$.

$\textbf{Theorem}$: If $(u_\epsilon)_{\epsilon >0}$ is an approximate identity, $1 \leq p < \infty$ and $f \in L^p(X, \mathbb{K})$, then $$u_\epsilon \star f \to_{\|.\|_p} f$$ where $\to_{\|.\|_p}$ denotes convergence in $L^p(X, \mathbb{K})$ wrt. the $L^p$-norm and $\star$ denotes the convolution, that is $g \star h(z) = \int_X g(x)h(x^{-1}z)d\lambda(x)$.

$\textbf{Proof:}$ For $p=1$ note, that
\begin{eqnarray}
\|f-u_\epsilon \star f\|_1 = \int |f-u_\epsilon \star f| d\lambda(x) = \int \bigg|f(x)\int u_\epsilon(y) d\lambda(y)- \int u_\epsilon(y)f(y^{-1}x) d\lambda(y) \bigg| d\lambda(x) \\ \leq \int \int |f(x)-f(y^{-1}x)| d\lambda(x) |u_\epsilon(y)| d\lambda(y)
\end{eqnarray}
Splitting $X = (X \backslash U) \cup U$ by means of the lemma for some $\delta>0$ leads to

\begin{eqnarray}
\|f-u_\epsilon \star f\|_1 \leq \int_U \int |f(x)-f(y^{-1}x)| d\lambda(x) |u_\epsilon(y)| d\lambda(y) + \int_{X \backslash U} \int |f(x)-f(y^{-1}x)| d\lambda(x) |u_\epsilon(y)| d\lambda(y) \\ \leq \delta \int |u_\epsilon| d\lambda(y) + 2 \|f\|_1 \int_{X\backslash U} |u_\epsilon| d\lambda(y) \leq \delta c + 2 \|f\|_1 \int_{X \backslash U} |u_\epsilon| d\lambda(y)
\end{eqnarray}
which can be made arbitrarily small by definition of an approximate identity. Now the author claims, that the case of $1 < p < \infty$ is analogous upon noting, that $\|\|h\|_1\|_p \leq \|\|h\|_p\|_1$ for a function $h$ in two variables.

---

I am somehow stuck at the case for $1 < p < \infty$ though. Since if we use $\|\|f\|_1\|_p \leq \|\|f\|_p\|_1$ then we can estimate:

$\begin{eqnarray}
\|f-u_\epsilon \star f\|_p = \big(\int |f-u_\epsilon \star f|^p d\lambda(x) \big)^{1/p} = \big(\int \bigg|\int \underbrace{(f(x)-f(y^{-1}x))u_\epsilon(y)}_{ = h(x,y)} d\lambda(y)\bigg|^p d\lambda(x) \big)^{1/p} \leq \big(\int \bigg|\int |h(x,y)| d\lambda(y)\bigg|^p d\lambda(x) \big)^{1/p} = \|\|h\|_1\|_p \leq \|\|h\|_p\|_1 = \int \big(\int |f(x)-f(y^{-1}x)|^p|u_\epsilon(y)|^p d\lambda(x)\big)^{1/p} d\lambda(y)
\end{eqnarray}$

> Now I guess we would be partitioning $X = (X\backslash U) \cup U$ as given in the lemma again. However my problem now is, that $\int |u_\epsilon|^p d\lambda(y)$ need not be finite in general (or does it?) and in addition we do not know if $\int_{X \backslash U} |u_\epsilon|^p d\lambda(y) \to 0$ as $\epsilon \to 0$. So how can we conclude our statement holds in the case of $1 < p < \infty$, since this doesn't seem to be analogous at all?

> Does someone have a reference for why $\|\|h\|_1\|_p \leq \|\|h\|_p\|_1$ even holds true?

$\textbf{Edit:}$ In the appendix of the lecture notes the aforementioned inequality is stated as follows:

For $1 \leq p <\infty$ and $h \colon X \times Y \to \mathbb{K}$ we have $$\|\|h\|_1\|_p \leq \|\|h\|_p\|_1$$ where $\|.\|_1$ and $\|.\|_p$ are with respect to $X$ and $Y$, respectively.

Comment: what does $\|\|h\|_1\|_p $ or $\|\|h\|_p\|_1$ mean?

Comment: If $h \colon X \times X \to \mathbb{K}$ then $$\|\|h(.,.)\|_1\|_p = \big(\int \|h(.,y)\|_1^p d\lambda(y) \big)^{1/p} =  \bigg(\int \bigg(\int |h(x,y)| d\lambda(x)\bigg)^p d\lambda(y) \bigg)^{1/p} $$ and analogously for $\|\|h\|_p\|_1$.

Comment: @alphaomega At least this is what I assume it means. It is not really defined in the lecture notes I am reading, but this seems to be the most plausible definition.

Comment: I think this is Minkoswki inequality https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minkowski_inequality#Minkowski%27s_integral_inequality. A generalization of
$$
\left|∫f \right| ≤ ∫\left|f \right|
$$
but with the $L^p$ norm instead

Comment: @LL see my Edit

Comment: I think the argument would be clearer if you don't refer to $L^p$, but simply to an arbitrary Banach space (or Frechet, or ...). The obviously analogous assertion is true in great generality, and it strikes me that the specifics of having the Banach space be $L^p$ are muddling things.

Comment: @paul garret I am not completely sure what you mean, but I'd be happy if you could elaborate a bit

Comment: Did you look at my link ?

Comment: @LL 3.14 Thanks you are right! I missed that at first.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $1 \leq p < \infty$ and let $f \in L^p(X, \mathbb{K})$, then it can be seen, either by direct verification or a duality argument, that $$\bigg(\int |f|^p d\lambda \bigg)^{1/p} = \max\limits_{\substack{g \in L^q(X, \mathbb{K}) \\ \|g\|_q = 1}} \bigg| \int fg d\lambda \bigg|$$ where $q$ is such that $1/p+1/q = 1$ and $\max$ indicates, that the supremum is attained. Having this in our toolbox we can state and prove the inequality

$\textbf{Minkowski's integral inequality:}$ Let $K(x,y)$ be a positive, measurable kernel on some product space $(\Omega_1 \times \Omega_2, \mu \times \nu)$. If $p \geq 1$, then $$\bigg(\int_{\Omega_1} \bigg(\int_{\Omega_2} K(x,y) d\nu \bigg)^p d\mu \bigg)^{1/p} \leq \int_{\Omega_2} \bigg(\int_{\Omega_1} K(x,y)^p d\mu \bigg)^{1/p} d\nu$$
$\mathbf{Proof:}$ If $p = 1$ the above inequality turns into an equality by Fubini. So let $p > 1$ and note that there exists $g \in L^q(X, \mathbb{K})$ with $\|g\|_q = 1$ such that $$\bigg(\int_{\Omega_1} \bigg(\int_{\Omega_2} K(x,y) d\nu \bigg)^p d\mu \bigg)^{1/p} = \int_{\Omega_1}g(x) \int_{\Omega_2} K(x,y) d\nu(y) d\mu(x)$$ Utilizing Fubini we note that

$\begin{eqnarray}
\int_{\Omega_1}g(x) \int_{\Omega_2} K(x,y) d\nu(y) d\mu(x) = \int_{\Omega_2} \int_{\Omega_1}g(x) K(x,y) d\mu(x) d\nu(y)\\ \leq \int_{\Omega_2} \sup\limits_{\|h\|_q = 1} \bigg| \int_{\Omega_1} h(x) K(x,y) d\mu(x) \bigg| d\nu(y) = \int_{\Omega_2} \bigg(\int_{\Omega_1} K(x,y)^p d\mu \bigg)^{1/p} d\nu
\end{eqnarray}$

as desired.

---

Now we get back to the main question and estimate

$\begin{eqnarray}
\|f-u_\epsilon \star f\|_p = \bigg(\int |f(x)-u_\epsilon \star f(x)|^p d\lambda(x) \bigg)^{1/p} = \bigg(\int \bigg|\int \big(f(x)-f(y^{-1}x)\big)u_\epsilon(y) d\lambda(y)\bigg|^p d\lambda(x) \bigg)^{1/p} \leq \int \bigg(\int |f(x)-f(y^{-1}x)|^p |u_\epsilon(y)|^p d\lambda(x) \bigg)^{1/p} d\lambda(y) = \int \bigg(\int |f(x)-f(y^{-1}x)|^p d\lambda(x) \bigg)^{1/p} |u_\epsilon(y)| d\lambda(y)
\end{eqnarray}$ which shows that as in the case of $p = 1$ we can split $X$ into $X = (X \backslash U) \cup U$ to verify, that $\|f - u_\epsilon \star f\|_p$ gets arbitrarily small for $\epsilon \to 0$. The real struggle with this question was, that i didn't notice the variables switching in the integral inequality, which is essential for the estimations.

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps this response is not as specific as might be desired, but I do think it is worth considering.

That is, for a (locally compact, Hausdorff, probably countably-based) topological group $G$ acting continuously on a locally convex, quasi-complete (e.g., complete), topological vector space $V$ (so $G\times V\to V$ is jointly continuous), for $\varphi\in L^1(G)$ and $v\in V$ let $\varphi\cdot v=\int_G \varphi(g)\cdot gv\;dg$ be the associated integral operator. Then for $\varphi$ running through an approximate identity, for all $v\in V$ we have $\varphi\cdot v\to v$ in the topology of $V$. This is more a property of vector-valued integrals than of the specifics of $V$.

Comment: Thanks a lot this is quite interesting. I think I now also know how my specific problem can be solved and I will write up an answer tomorrow for future reference.

Comment: @paulgarrett could you please provide a reference?